# JSF2.2 passing parameter from one view to another view

Tags: jsf

I am working on a JSF application whose homepage has a search input field with a command button to submit the search. Once the user clicks the search button it should search and show the results page. I am having problem with passing the parameter from the home view to the results view. My code is as follows :

```
<h:form id="searchForm">
<p:inputText styleClass="enterSearch" size="50" value="#{searchController.searchText}" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode === 13) {document.getElementById('searchForm:submitSearch').click();
    return false;
 }"/>
<p:commandButton id="submitSearch" styleClass="enterSearch" value="Search" label="Search" action="#{searchController.search(searchController.searchText)}" />
</h:form>
```

Bean is

```
@ManagedBean(name = "searchController")
@ViewScoped
public class SearchController implements Serializable {
.....
public String search(String query) {            
//What goes here?   Use FacesContext Attributes?  
return "searchResults";
}
...
```

The search method returns searchResults.xhtml page
This page displays the search results. How can I pass the search query to the searchResults view and initialize the backing bean for searchResults? Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `SearchController` should actually pass the results (not the query) to the `searchResults` view. The way I'd do this is by moving the `search` method to the results page:

**searchResults.xhtml:**

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="searchQuery" value="#{searchController.searchText}" />
  <f:viewAction listener="#{searchController.update()}" />
</f:metadata>

<h:dataTable value="#{searchController.results}">
  <!-- your data -->
</h:dataTable>
```

**SearchController.java:**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SearchController implements Serializable {
    private String searchText; // +getter/setter
    private List<String> results; // +getter

    public void update() {            
        results = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"My", "Results"});
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to simply point your search form to the `searchResults` site:

```
<h:inputText value="#{searchController.searchText}" />
<h:commandLink action="searchResults" value="Search" />
```

Note that this is kind of a hack, so let me suggest alternatives:

1. Stay on the same page. Since you can conditionally render elements, just hide your result display with a `rendered="#{not empty searchController.results}"`. So easy.
2. Don't use POST, but GET. This is exactly what [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for) is about (and a lot more).